# System does not recognize OS after USB removal

Tags: windows, operating-system, usb

Recently, I add an SSD with a caddy to my laptop, then I used a USB to set up the Operating System.

The OS works properly, and even it will be run after a restart. However, when I shot down the laptop and unplug the USB, It says that OS was not found on the hard drive.

I removed the USB and restart the laptop. I expect that the laptop cannot run the OS, but it could.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may have to provide more details to get help with your problem (which might not fit perfectly to StackOverflow, btw, see [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), e.g. your `grub.cfg` in case you use Grub as a bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the USB one should change the BIOS to Boot from Hard Drive, and it will be OK.